# Caching web app launched from home screen on iOS

Tags: ios, html, caching, web-applications, mobile-safari

So I've built this web app game with HTML 5 and javascript (mainly jQuery). It's meant to be used on an iPad in a location where there's no wireless internet (a museum).
I am using a cache.manifest file to cache all the files needed for the game to work. And on my desktop using both Chrome and Safari this works great. I can see all the files listed in the application cache in the debugger and the app runs perfectly without internet connection.
Testing it on the iPad's browser also gave good results. It seems to take a bit longer for the iPad to cache all the files but if you give it enough time the app works in safari on iOS in airplane mode as well.

Now here's the problem. When I install the app to the home screen and launch it from there the app doesn't work. Only the first page will run and when I try to go to the next one it'll fail and tell me I need internet. (The second HTML page is loaded after the map appears and you've chosen hall 1)

I've read that it might need to cache all over again if launched from the home screen so I've tried waiting for it to cache and then going to the next page. I've waited for 2-3 minutes yet it still didn't work.

You can find the app [here](http://jorgoscoenen.be/m/spel/). It's in Dutch so it might be a little confusing.

The manifest file is [here](http://jorgoscoenen.be/m/spel/cache.manifest).

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out myself.
Turns out it was a real rookie mistake. I had some bad references to the cache.manifest file in some of the pages of the app. And on an iOS device that seems to cause some problems.

Pretty confusing since it worked fine in a regular browser. But lesson learned: iOS is very picky when it comes to little details and you need to have a reference to the manifest-file on every page.